# How can I install R version 4.1.1 in macOS?

Tags: r, macos

I did not find that specific version in the R previous releases for macOS. I was only able to find the last version of R.

https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/

Comment: I was looking for the same and it worked to just adjust the url to the pkg file: https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/base/R-4.1.1.pkg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find it here normally

https://cran.r-project.org/src/base/R-4/